# FTP user group & previous file and folder permissions is not getting assigned

Tags: server, 20.04, permissions, ssh, ftp

I have successfully created a group(`zep_group`) and a few FTP user accounts(`zep_user_1`, `zep_user_2`, `zep_user_3`) within the same group(`zep_group`) on my Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS).

I have uploaded base folders and files and done permission settings with folder/directory permissions as `775` and `664` for the files. I checked the permission by using the command `ls -al` I can see all folders have been assigned with user:group(`zep_user_1:zep_group`)

After I tried to upload some new files and folders via FileZilla with the `zep_user_1` login, those files and folders were getting assigned with the group like - `zep_user_1:zep_user_1` along with the wrong folders permission as `700`.

Then I need to re-login with SSH and manually change the group for the new files & folders permission, which I don't want to do every time after a single file/folder is uploaded by the same user.

I just wanted to upload new files & folders with the permission of `775` for folders & `664` for files and with the owner and group like - `zep_user_1:zep_group`. Is there any way to fix this permanently in Ubuntu?

Comment: FTP is obsolete and is a security risk. Since you are already able to log in with SSH, why don't you use that? Simply add `sftp://` in front of the server name and use your SSH credentials.

Comment: [@Daniel T](https://askubuntu.com/users/1004020/daniel-t), I have created the sub-user FTP accounts for my developer teams, each has separate folders. That's why I'm not using SFTP.

Comment: [@Daniel T](https://askubuntu.com/users/1004020/daniel-t) Still I'm having the same issue. Is there any fix can you suggest to me that I can try now to fix this issue?